# Clarification on HTML file paths

Tags: html, css, filepath

I am new to this.
I have a funny situation where my file paths for images show up fine for the images linked in my index.html file, but not for the background image that I have set in my css file.

Images for both files are located in the same place. Root directory< img folder< images are here.

My image code in the HTML  looks like this:
<src="img/imgname.extension" alt="something" />
My image code for the background in the css looks like this:
background: url("img/imgname.extension")

Is this file path correct?

Comment: Where is your CSS file located??

Comment: root< css folder < css doc

Answer (score 1):

URLs for CSS files are relative to the URL of the CSS file, not the HTML document that loads the CSS file.

Presumably, your CSS file is at `(root)/css/style.css` or similar, so you could need to go up a level (`../`) to get to the root before going down into the `img` directory.

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed it! Also, the  explanation really helped.